# What's the purpose of 'coder' in matlab?

Tags: matlab

I was seeing the built-in function `estimateFundamentalMatrix` and it looks like as follows

```
function r = checkOutputClassStrings(list, value)

potentialMatch = validatestring(value, list, ...
  'estimateFundamentalMatrix', 'OutputClass');
coder.internal.errorIf(~strcmpi(value, potentialMatch), ...
  'vision:estimateFundamentalMatrix:invalidOutputClassString');
r = 1;
```

I was curious about the `coder.internal.errorIf` function. I guessed that `coder` is a system object that shows internal states of a function, but I don't know exactly.

Comment: It's fairly self-descriptive... return an internal error if (...), where in this case the error check is `~strcmpi(x,y)`, i.e. 'not (case insensitive) string compare result of `x` and `y`. When editing built-in functions, expect to see lower level error handling.

Comment: Is there any reason using 'coder.internal.errorIf' instead of just using strcmpi?

Comment: `strcmpi` does not create an error if there isn't a match, it just returns a Boolean output (this is a documented function you can read about)... You would have to replace this with `if ~strcmpi(x,y); error( 'Error message' ); end`. Since this is a built-in function, there's no need for them to be so verbose, they can jump directly to the internal conditional error.

Comment: Thank you very much!! I got it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm just formalising the answer I gave in the comments...

- The `coder.internal.errorIf` is exactly what the name suggests. It's an internal command to conditionally issue an error.
- The [`strcmpi`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strcmpi.html) function performs a case insensitive string compare, and returns a Boolean (true/false) value.
- The tilde (`~`) negates the result of the call to `strcmpi`.

So the line you're curious about is *somewhat* equivalent to this on the surface:

```
% Use strcmpi for case insensitive string comparison
if ~strcmpi(value, potentialMatch)
    % When using 'error', the string must be specified along with the message identifier.
    % The errorIf command was leveraging the in-built 'message' catalog.
    % In this case I've lifted the error message from calling the original errorIf command.
    error('vision:estimateFundamentalMatrix:invalidOutputClassString', ...
          'Expected OutputClass to be ''double'' or ''single''');
end
```

The `code.internal.errorIf` command is, as pointed out in other answers and comments, a different construct than the common `error` command, which allows MATLAB to optimise C code generation (hence why it is in the `coder` package).

For more coder-specific details, see [Sam's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51820401/3978545).

Comment: Not really - commands from the `coder` package are from MATLAB Coder, and help in the conversion of MATLAB code to C code. See my answer.

Comment: @Sam What do you mean 'not really'? From reading your answer, it appears my comment about it being "lower level" might be a bad phrasing (although the C code is arguably lower level than MATLAB), but you can enter the mentioned functions using `edit` and everything I've said here appears to be true?

Comment: /1 So you're right that `coder.internal.errorIf` is a command that conditionally issues an error. Indeed, if you type `edit coder.internal.errorIf`, you'll see that it basically does exactly that. But note that it does so using `assert`, not using `error`. Contrary to your suggestion, the indirection using an extra function call and an `assert` rather than an `error` will slightly slow things down, rather than "save time" by "leveraging a lower level command".

Comment: /2  The reason it's done like this is because MATLAB can use the information provided by `assert` commands to optimise the generation of C code (this is not true of `error`). In particular, it knows that in code after the `assert`, the assert condition will be true, and it can use that fact to reason about the code, and produce better C code.

Comment: /3 So the reason I write "not really" is that although nothing you've said is wrong, you haven't explained the main purpose of the command, which is not just another way of throwing an error, but rather a specific instruction to MATLAB to help optimise C code generation. Hope that's useful - no downvote for your answer though.

Comment: @Sam Thanks for the explanation, makes sense. I've made some minor tweaks to my answer.

Answer (score 4):

`coder` is a package that is part of the [MATLAB Coder](https://uk.mathworks.com/products/matlab-coder.html) product.

MATLAB Coder allows you to convert a subset of the MATLAB language into C code - the C code can then subsequently be incorporated into wider C applications, or brought back into MATLAB via the MEX interface, or delivered to an embedded device. When using MATLAB Coder, you will include commands from the `coder` package within your MATLAB code - they typically have no effect on the code when it is run within MATLAB, but when converting to C code they help you to control the way it is converted, by adding additional information necessary to help with the conversion (for example, by controlling the inlining of a function, or specifying that a for-loop should be unrolled).

Some toolboxes, including the Computer Vision Toolbox that contains the code snippet you refer to, explicitly support the use of MATLAB Coder to generate C code from them, in that they make sure to only use the subset of the MATLAB language that is convertible into C, and they include `coder` commands to help optimise their conversion into C.

The command you're seeing here says that, when converting the MATLAB code into C, it should include an explicit check in the C code to compare `value` with `potentialMatch`, and exit with an error if they don't match.

(I'll be honest - I'm not entirely sure why this is necessary. As far as I can see, if the code has got past the `validatestrings` statement, then by definition it should always pass the test in the subsequent statement. Seems a bit redundant to me, but maybe I'm overlooking some detail).